# TWebBrowser: How to know the URL in a OnNewWindow2 event?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, twebbrowser

We have HTML with:

`<A target="_blank" href="http://blabla.com">`

When the link is clicked the `OnNewWindow2` is fired:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1NewWindow2(Sender: TObject;
  var ppDisp: IDispatch; var Cancel: WordBool);
begin
  Cancel := True;  
  // open in default browser
end;
```

I want to open the link in the default browser:
[Opening TWebBrowser link in default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556943/opening-twebbrowser-link-in-default-browser)

But no `BeforeNavigate2`is fired in my case.
How can I know the intended URL in a `TWebBrowser` `OnNewWindow2` event?

---

EDIT: In newer versions of Delphi there is a [`OnNewWindow3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa768337(v%3Dvs.85)) event which provides the URL I need. currently I'm really struggling to begin to understand how to implement this event into an existing `TWebBrowser`.
If anyone has done this, it would be great to get some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the [`InvokeEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.InvokeEvent) method of the browser and wait there for the `DISPID_NEWWINDOW3` dispatch identifier. For an interposer class such [`OnNewWindow3`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.OnNewWindow3) event could be implemented like this:

```
uses
  ActiveX, OleCtrls, SHDocVw;

const
  DISPID_NEWWINDOW3 = 273;

type
  TWebBrowserNewWindow3 = procedure(ASender: TObject; var ppDisp: IDispatch; var Cancel: WordBool;
    dwFlags: Longint; const bstrUrlContext: WideString; const bstrUrl: WideString) of object;

  TWebBrowser = class(SHDocVw.TWebBrowser)
  private
    FOnNewWindow3: TWebBrowserNewWindow3;
  protected
    procedure InvokeEvent(ADispID: TDispID; var AParams: TDispParams); override;
  public
    property OnNewWindow3: TWebBrowserNewWindow3 read FOnNewWindow3 write FOnNewWindow3;
  end;

implementation

procedure TWebBrowser.InvokeEvent(ADispID: TDispID; var AParams: TDispParams);
begin
  if (ADispID = DISPID_NEWWINDOW3) and Assigned(FOnNewWindow3) then
  begin
    FOnNewWindow3(Self, AParams.rgvarg^[4].pdispVal^, AParams.rgvarg^[3].pbool^,
      AParams.rgvarg^[2].lVal, WideString(AParams.rgvarg^[1].bstrVal), WideString(AParams.rgvarg^[0].bstrVal));
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Very elegant and interesting solution!

Comment: This is almost exactly the code I was writing after you posted your comment, but dealing with the `TDispParams` was just too much for me. well done! :)
One question, how did you figured out that the Params are in revers order in the array?

Comment: Well, I've just copy pasted this code from my post on a forum I used to participate :) How did I discover that reverse order (nor exact Delphi version for which that code was for) I can't remember. [P.S. I don't have any Delphi by hand right now]

Answer (score 2):

> How can I know the intended URL in a TWebBrowser OnNewWindow2 event?

You can use DOM's [getAttribute method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752280(v%3Dvs.85)). But before you should load needed page and after this done replace particular events with your own. See code below:

```
uses
  ...
  SHDocVw, MSHTML;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
    // Your auto-generated event handler
    procedure WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject; 
      const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);

  private
    // Your self-written event handlers
    procedure New_BeforeNavigate2(ASender: TObject;
      const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers: OleVariant; 
      var Cancel: WordBool);
    procedure New_NewWindow2(ASender: TObject; var ppDisp: IDispatch; var Cancel: WordBool);
  end;

...

// Assign event handler in design-time
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; 
  const URL: OleVariant);
begin
  (ASender as TWebBrowser).OnBeforeNavigate2 := New_BeforeNavigate2;
  (ASender as TWebBrowser).OnNewWindow2 := New_NewWindow2;
end;

procedure TForm1.New_BeforeNavigate2(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; 
  const URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers: OleVariant; 
  var Cancel: WordBool);
begin
  ShowMessage('New URL will be: ' + URL);
  Cancel := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.New_NewWindow2(ASender: TObject; var ppDisp: IDispatch; var Cancel: WordBool);
var
  S: String;
begin
  S := ((TWebBrowser(ASender).Document as IHTMLDocument2).ActiveElement as IHTMLElement).GetAttribute('href', 0);
  ShowMessage('New window''s URL is: ' + S);
  Cancel := true;
end;
```

Now you can get URL even with `OnNewWindow2` event. For the case `target="_self"` there is also `OnBeforeNavigate2` event handler. It should work if I correctly got your question.

Comment: This is indeed a nice hack. I will do some tests to see how consistent it is.

Comment: This worked for the cases I tested and it is really an original idea! (although I wonder if the `ActiveElement` might be somehow changed from the moment you clicked the link and the moment the event fired...)  but I think that @TLama's solution is the ultimate approach. Thanks  :)